# Query not returning results in PHP for blank variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A SELECT statement does not return values when run from PHP when the parameter is left blank. The same statement if run from the MYSQL query window works just fine for the above condition.

This is the SELECT statement in MYSQL

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1=IFNULL(:var1,field1);
```

This is the code in PHP.

```
if(isset($_GET['var1'])){
$var1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['var1']);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 
         field1= IFNULL('$var1',field1)";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

When the variable var1 is left blank the query should fetch all the records. If there is a value put in for var1 then only that record is to be displayed. This works fine. The problem is when the variable var1 is left blank. No records are displayed.

Please note running the SELECT statement in MYSQL query window for both the scenarios works perfectly.

Just an update: I tried putting a default value ('ALL') for the field(var1) in my HTML form which calls the PHP code. 
I then changed the SELECT statement in the PHP code as below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1  WHERE 
         field1= COALESCE('$var1','ALL',field1)";
```

Even this does not work. Guys there has to be some way to do this.

Comment: As you build up the field your testing as `IFNULL('$var1',field1)` - the first field can only ever be `''` - which can never be null.

Comment: but,in PHP block you use `var1` after WHERE instead of `field1`(within `$sql`)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan that was a typo. I have edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @NigelRen so this way will not work in PHP? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WHERE` clause only if the variable is not null :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1" ;
if(isset($_GET['var1'])){
    $var1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['var1']);
    $sql .= " WHERE field1 = '$var1'" ;
}

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done. Use if statement and have 2 separate queries for the 2 scenarios.

```
if (isset($_GET['var1'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * from table1 WHERE field1=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['var1']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
} else {
    $result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM table1');
}
```

Pay attention to how I used `query()`. You can only use that method if you do not have variables to be put inside of SQL. If you have some variable data you need to use placeholders and then bind it using `bind_param()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
// New Connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');
// Check for errors
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1" ;
if(isset($_GET['var1'])){
  $var1=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['var1']);
  $sql .= " WHERE field1 = '$var1'" ;
}
$result = $db->query($sql);
if($result){
  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    $rlt_arr[] = $row;
  }
  $result->close();
  $db->next_result();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to add nullif

```
select
    *
from
    table1
where
    field1 = ifnull(nullif('$var1', ''), field1)
```

Comment: after you update your code, so it returns a default value 'ALL', `field1 = ifnull(nullif('$var1', 'ALL'), field1)` should work